# setting uri image as props in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, image, uri, react-props

I'd like to pass an uri of an Image as a props in React native.

My code looks like this in the child component :

`const ButtonIcon= ({ uri }) => { return ( <Image  style={{ width: 24, height: 24, resizeMode: 'contain', }} source={{ uri:{uri} }}/> ) }`

Here is the code in the parent component :

`<ButtonIcon  uri="../assets/googleicon.png" /> <ButtonIcon />`

I have a message saying JSON value "..." cannot be converted to a valid URL.
Anybody can help please?
I'm using expo with react native.
Thank you.

Comment: use `require('../assets/googleicon.png')`

Comment: doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a local path as a URI for `Image` component
Instead, do something like this

```
const ButtonIcon= ({ source }) => { 
  return (
    <Image
      style={{ width: 24, height: 24, resizeMode: 'contain' }}
      source={source} />
  ) 
}
```

```
<ButtonIcon source={require('../assets/googleicon.png')} />
```

Refer to https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#source for more information

Comment: Thank you so much, it works like a charme!!!! you make my day dude!